# SQL Query using inner join with a subquery which 0 line

Tags: sql, join, subquery, correlated-subquery

In my query, I select a column which cannot exist because this column comes from a subquery in a join. (The subquery can give me 0 lines)

Consequently, in this case, I want to select 0 instead of "temp.Quantity" column.

The code:

```
SELECT
    bx.BX_BoxNum,
    temp.Quantity    -- <- this column
FROM BOX bx
INNER JOIN (SELECT BX_Id, SUM(BX_Quantity) AS Quantity FROM BOX
            WHERE BX_Top_S = 'True' GROUP BY BX_Id) temp
    ON bx.BX_Id = temp.BX_Id
WHERE bx.BX_BoxNum = 10
```

Sometimes a box number is empty! And I try to have a line with "BOX n°10 -- 0" instead of nothing

Could you please help me?

Comment: No problem with a language barrier. We share one language in common, t-sql. Here is a great article to get you started on conversing this type of thing in our common tongue. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Use a outter join (usualy a left join) if the you want ot return results even if the second query/subquery returns nothing and you don't want a null use coalesce to turn it in a zero

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT bx.BX_BoxNum, ISNULL(temp.Quantity, 0)
FROM BOX bx
left outer JOIN (SELECT BX_Id, SUM(BX_Quantity) AS Quantity FROM BOX 
WHERE BX_Top_S = 'True' GROUP BY BX_Id) temp ON bx.BX_Id = temp.BX_Id
WHERE bx.BX_BoxNum = 10
```

Outer joins allow selects to happen when one side of a join returns nothing. Inner Joins have to have rows on both sides of the join (as you've found!). Google for the differences between LEFT, RIGHT and FULL Outer joins.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT bx.BX_BoxNum, SUM(COALESCE(temp.Quantity, 0)) AS Quantity
FROM BOX bx
    LEFT JOIN BOX temp ON bx.BX_Id = temp.BX_Id AND temp.BX_Top_S = 'True'
WHERE bx.BX_BoxNum = 10
GROUP BY bx.BX_BoxNum
```

Comment: thanks for your help but i needed a subquery because the query i wrote here is a simplificated version of my real query.. ^^

Comment: The main idea - you should use LEFT/RIGHT OUTER JOIN instead of INNER JOIN.
Only in this case you can get "BOX n°10 -- 0" if subquery won't return any records.